# Use DataContext.CreateDatabase in SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I am trying to re-deploy my ASP.NET MVC3 application across several different environments and would like to try using SQL Azure. I'd like to use my existing LINQ structure and CreateDatabase to create these databases.

I am wondering how I can use [CreateDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx) with SQL Azure since the USE statement doesn't work on the platform.

Please answer with any suggestions or if there might be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336274.aspx

> **Important**: The CREATE DATABASE
>   statement must be the only statement
>   in a Transact-SQL batch. You must be
>   connected to the master database when
>   executing the CREATE DATABASE
>   statement.

You'll have to find a way to fit in this premise. Maybe it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried executing this?

I've deployed nHibernate apps to SQL Azure - these apps call CREATE DATABASE somewhere inside the nHibernate layer and they work OK.

Best advice I can give is to try it - then come back with any specific errors you see. There may be some changes to make, but I think these should be small.

Comment: On Azure, I believe CREATE DATABASE works but you can't then switch to that database using USE.

Comment: If the only problem is the CREATE DATABASE problem, then just make that line the one difference in your deployment - i.e. "if" that functionality out for Azure deployments and use a connection string that attaches directly to the correct pre-created database. You can still run all the same CREATE TABLE statements.