# Linq DataContext.CreateDatabase on Azure

Tags: linq, azure, linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database

This came up once before: [Use DataContext.CreateDatabase in SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214621/use-datacontext-createdatabase-in-sql-azure)

The answer accepted was "maybe it's not possible". Didn't seem like a full answer.

I have a set of classes fully defined and I am wanting to create a database on Azure for this.  It's not working because the USE statement does not work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336288.aspx

So, the database gets created as blank, and internally Linq generates a USE statement to move to that database and start adding tables. This fails and it throws an exception.

So how can I create my database? Can I use Linq to add tables to an existing database? Can I enable USE on Azure somehow? Seems ridiculous this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around for a while on this, I ended up creating the database against a local SQL Server instance.  Then used SQL Server Management Studio -> Tasks -> Script Database, and turned on the export type to be Microsoft Azure. Then I had the script file needed to run on the Azure server. I'll leave the question open for a day or two because I am curious if this can work with Azure directly somehow. If I don't hear anything, I will close it.

Answer (score 0):

The USE statement does not switch between databases in Azure SQL Database. You will have to connect to the database to create a table on that database.

Regards
Dhruv